# Mocking/Unittesting when using Node serialport callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I am working on a web-interface for a 3rd party device that connects via serial port. Example code below...

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

sp.on("data", function (rawData) {
...
```

My question is how can I mock/Unittest the sp "data" event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emit the 'data' event at will because `SerialPort` implements [the `EventEmitter` interface](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2). Just use `.emit()`.

This code will log "woot" to the console even though the serial interface didn't actually receive any data. It fakes it with `.emit()`.

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttys000", {
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

sp.on("data", function (rawData) {
    console.log('woot');
});

sp.emit('data');
```

Comment: Thanks... I also just realized that I don't have to do an in-line function and by replacing it with a normal function I will be able to test the data processing function without the need of a SerialPort.